# Calculation of $\nu$ and $\gamma$ in one-class SVM with rbf kernel

Tags: svm, python, scikit-learn, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I am using python sklearn's one-class svm classifier for anomaly detection. I would like to know can I accurately calculate the required value for nu and gamma for rbf kernel. Is there any equation or theory to calculate nu and gamma according to dataset?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. An informed choice can be given by properly cross-validated fine tuning.